# Open jar file with python using .desktop file

Tags: java, python, linux, python-3.x

I have a program in .jar file. For run it, I need open terminal and use "java -jar .jar" command to run the program.

Now I want to create a desktop file, and when I double-click it run a python file that have the command to start my jar program.

But the problem is: while using the jar program, terminal must be open, if terminal close, program close too.

I create a python file and I run it in terminal. The code works fine. But when I try to use the .desktop file to run the python code, I got a error saying "Error: Unable to access jarfile .jar", and terminal close.

code.py

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', '<filename>.jar'])
```

program.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=python /home/user/Downloads/code.py
Name= test
Terminal=true
```

Comment: Your jar file needs to be placed relative along with code.py. Looks like you ae executing code.py in the downloads directory. Is your jar file in the same directory?

Comment: Yes, the code.py and the jar file are in same directory. When I run the code.py in terminal, the jar program run. But using the program.desktop I got the error.

Comment: Why do you want puthon to run your jar file? It is possible to just write that `java -jar file.jar` in Exec. For example of such .desktop file is made here: https://askubuntu.com/a/633382